# Service Fabric: Is it possible to run both Linux and Windows nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to run both Linux and Windows nodes within the same cluster on Azure Service Fabric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is currently not possible.

Comment: Is it on the road map? queriosly if the demand is not there or if there are some technical blockers. Would be cool if the nuget packages for unix/windows shared versionnumbers and could be used with dotnet core nuget packages :)

Comment: It's something we want to do down the line. Shared dot net core packages across linux and windows would definitely be cool.

Comment: I thought that I am able to create a Service Fabric Cluster with one `NodeType` using Windows Server 2016 and another `NodeType` using Linux Ubuntu, but then I realized after this question that I cannot do that. Is there any technical restriction why is it not possible? Is it on the road map?

Comment: @VaclavTurecek -still not possible?

Comment: @VaclavTurecek -still not possible?