# How do I configure Service Fabric Cluster on Windows Server 2016 to be able to run Linux Containers?

Tags: linux, azure-service-fabric, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

In one of our project, we have a technical constraint to use Service Fabric as platform to run applications built with Service Fabric SDK. The Service Fabric Cluster will use Windows Server 2016 for the Operating System.

However, the software also are depending on a 3rd party product that run as Docker Container running on Linux Container OS.

The Product Owner would like to have the Container to be deployed on the same Service Fabric cluster for easier management and monitoring.

It is known that Windows Server 2016 are able to run Linux Docker Container using Hyper-V Isolation Technology. How do I configure Service Fabric running on Windows Server 2016 to be able to utilize that technology and run Linux Containers?

Thank you.

Comment: @jww It's platform development question same like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148950/service-fabric-is-it-possible-to-run-both-linux-and-windows-nodes

Comment: @jww I've edited the question, now I need specific configuration for Service Fabric. Service Fabric is a PaaS for running hyper-scale applications and orchestrating containers, it surely does not fit in Super User.

Comment: @jww Please tell me how to improve my question so I can convince you to remove your downvote and close vote. Thank you.

Comment: @jww this is also platform development question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995973/linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2016?rq=1

Comment: @jww that's hardly constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for running Linux containers directly on [WinSrv2016](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2017/04/18/dockercon-2017-powering-new-linux-innovations-with-hyper-v-isolation-and-windows-server/) is on the way. It's **not** here yet. Therefore you can't run them on SF yet either.

You can't have a hybrid cluster either. So at this time your options is: run two SF clusters.