# Is Linux and Windows in one cluster supported on Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there a possibility to have mixed windows and linux work nodes on Azure Service Fabric, or the cluster must be homogeneous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is still not possible.

Was also asked before as well:

[Service Fabric: Is it possible to run both Linux and Windows nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148950/service-fabric-is-it-possible-to-run-both-linux-and-windows-nodes)