# Service Fabric - Linux and Windows in the same cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I don't think this is possible but i figured i would ask.  We have an existing onPrem Service Fabric cluster running on Windows VMs.  That's great for the .NET side of the house but for Java they may want to run Linux VMs instead of Windows.

If we wanted to set up an onPrem Linux Node type can i add this to the existing cluster or do we need a new cluster.  I would assume we need a new cluster but... you never know until you ask.  Considering the security is windows specific I didn't think this was possible?

Thanks in advance, 
Greg

Comment: This was asked a couple of times already. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57501925/5946937

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Linux and Windows in one cluster supported on Azure Service Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434695/is-linux-and-windows-in-one-cluster-supported-on-azure-service-fabric)